# I have a Compiler problem and a question regarding it

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, codeblocks

The problem appears to be very simple to describe, but hard to understand. I am hoping someone who is experienced can help me:
Very simple, again:

1. When I compile my C code or program through Code::Blocks (mingw installation), it works perfectly fine and generates a 54kb file that works precisely as intended. (yay).
2. BUT when I compile the same C code or program through gcc, both in cmd and in emacs - compilation is successful (41kb filesize) , however: The code, like, half finishes when I execute it. (??) It doesn't print what it is supposed to (or anything). It just starts, then ends (rapidly on cmd). Regardless of if I run it in shell or cmd, or on codeblocks own cmd-thing. (that is, if I compile it thrugh gcc, and then execute the main.exe file through codeblocks).

(3. EXTRA: The program in question is the problem in the C programming book question 1.13: It takes in a bunch of words, and checks their lengths, and then prints out a vertical histogram using
'|' lines. It executes perfectly well when I compile it via Code::blocks; but when I run it through gcc on emacs or cmd it just works a little then quits without printing any lines at all.
So I know it is a compiler issue, but I have no idea how to fix it. I would prefer to compile through gcc in the futuree, but if the codeblocks version of compiling is better then I have no choice but to abandon gcc? Or do I? You tell me, since I am very stupid in this matter.

I've done a couple of backs and forths (delete main.exe, and recompile it using both. Same results: codeblocks works, gcc does not.) - the exe file that is. compilation is "successful" on both -but the gcc version does not execute as it should.

My completely useless guess is that the getchar() function acts weirdly depending on what compiler is using it.

Thank you in advance!

I will add the code in question incase you need it, or if you want to judge me. (I won't mind any criticism.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 25  /* Maximum length of input. */

int main(){

    /* Histogram of length of words in its input. Vertical or Horizontal. (Vertical is hardest, so let's do that!).
     * Identify words and count characters within each, store that length in a array that represents the length for each word.
     * Draw based on the number of words, their lengths, and their maximum height (optional).
     */

    /* Identify when inside of a word, start counting. When leaving word, record c-count into array, reset count to 0 after.
     * Until entering new word.
     */
    
    //Declaration of the Counter's variables here
    //The Histogram's variables are farther down below!
    int nw, c, cCount, wordLen[MAXLENGTH];
    int i = nw = cCount = 0;
    
    //Initialize wordLen into 0 to avoid garbage results from any potential unused members of the array.
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    wordLen[i] = 0;
    }

    //Counts characters in each word and stores inside of chronological array.
    while ((c = getchar())!= EOF){
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){ 
        wordLen[nw] = cCount;
        ++nw;
        cCount = 0;
        
    }
    else {
        ++cCount; 
    }
        
    
    
    }
    //Prints first 4 words lengths for comparison purposes.
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n\n", wordLen[0], wordLen[1], wordLen[2], wordLen[3]);

    //Declaration of variables for Histogram.
    int currentLvl, largestN, ii, iii, IV, V;

    //Finds and stores the  largest number from the array into var:largestN.
    for (ii = 0; ii < MAXLENGTH; ii++) {
    if (wordLen[ii] >= largestN)
        largestN = wordLen[ii];
    }

    //Declare and initialize array for comparison purposes for later use in the Histogram generation process.
    int level[largestN];
    level[0] = 0;
    for (iii = 1; iii < largestN + 1; iii++){
    level[iii] = iii;
    }
    // printf("\n largest N is %d\n", largestN); //for testing
    // printf("wordLen 0 is: %d\n", wordLen[0]); //for testing
    

    /* Histogram generation:
     * The logic is simple: From Top-left, move rightwards (in chronological order) and check which of the words' lengths
     * reach the current level or height (starting from Top). Print a line at that spot if they ever do, print an empty space if
     * they do not.
     * Then move one step down, and repeat the process but comparing 1 level lower. Until bottom is reached.
     */
    //ss
    for (V = largestN; V > 0; V--){
    currentLvl = level[V];
    
    for (IV = 0; IV < MAXLENGTH; IV++){
        if (wordLen[IV] >= currentLvl)
        printf("|");
        
        else {
        printf(" ");
    }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    
    }
    

    
    return 0;
}
```

edit 1:

Example of when I compile + run it through codeblocks:

(

This is a sentence:

```
asdasdasd
4 2 1 8

            |
          | |
          | |
          | |
          | |
    |     | |
    |     | |
    | |   | |
    | | | | |
```

)

This is using emacs (after using gcc compiler) - shell :

(

b:\c-programs\Examples>main.exe
main.exe

This is a sentence asdasdasd

b:\c-programs\Examples>
Process shell finished

)

Oh, small thing I forgot to add: I have to do ctrl-d or ctrl-c to "finish" the program after typing the sentence for it to start printing the graph. Maybe that has something to do with it?

edit 2: It looks really weird here, but in the comment field/on the cmd screen it looks fine (the codeblocks one that is).

edit 3: *fixing some missing information in the edit section.*

edit 4: **Solved** Thank you everyone for your inputs, I will read and learn as much as I can from each and every one of you! The problem was as it seems that I did not initialize largestN (as you said), but I also learned a lot of other things which I will try to absorb! So thank you! Wish you the luck I had for your projects too!!

Comment: Can you provide sample input, expected output, and actual output (when it doesn't work)?

Comment: It sounds to me like you’re invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you both (was 3, so thank you to him/her too!). I posted the input, expected output, and actual output as you requested I think. As for the invoking undefined behaviour, how come the Code::Blocks compiler gets it but gcc does not? What do I have to do to fix this (and fix it permanently)? (going to sleep now if I dont respond for a while). Thank you again

Comment: If you invoke undefined behaviour, that means literally anything can happen. It can start playing Space Invaders, email a message to your parents, or even appear to work normally.

Comment: The difference in executable file size is not inherently meaningful, except inasmuch as it shows that the files are different.  My guess would be that the larger one contains debug symbols, and the smaller one not.  There might also be a difference in optimization level, which can affect file size.

Comment: fyi you can do `wordLen[MAXLENGTH] = {0};` to initialize the array to 0, no need for the `for` loop.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings -wall

Comment: Very often, if the programs produced by two different compilers (or even different optimization options with one compiler) give different answers for the same input, you have UB — undefined behaviour — in your code.  That's a good signal to look hard at your code.  Also, using GCC compiler options such as `-O3 -g -Werror -Wall -Wextra` (as a starting point — there are many more warnings that could be added) will give you lots of clues about where your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You might have some errors in your code. Here you are comparing `wordLen[ii]` with `largestN` which isnt initialized and could have any value.

```
int currentLvl, largestN, ii, iii, IV, V;

//Finds and stores the  largest number from the array into var:largestN.
for (ii = 0; ii < MAXLENGTH; ii++) {
    if (wordLen[ii] >= largestN)
        largestN = wordLen[ii];
}
```

What if `largestN` holds some value like `641346` and you try to create an array with it here:

```
int level[largestN];
```

And by the way you can have one variable for multiple loop.

```
//int i, ii, iii, IV, V;    // dont do this
int i;    // do this
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    // do something
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){    // use the same variable again
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Oh that made it work! That makes so much sense actually! Yea, the largestN was probably a random garbage (I think its called that) value, so when I tried to compared wordLen[]s to it, it failed!!! Thank you everyone! It seems the undefined behaviour came from this little black hole of a problem! i must be much more careful with my initialization process! Huge logical errors can occur!!! I'm testing it now, and it works (with gcc)!!! I tried removing the initialization again, and it failed as expected; thenreadded, and it works again!

Comment: Also, C arrays are indexed from zero, so the maximum valid index for an array declared as `level[largestN]` is `largestN - 1`.  But the code given attempts to access index `largestN` of that array, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Oh yea, that makes sense! Thank you. I will have to internalize lots of things to become a good/great programmer, such as the ( - 1) habit for certain situations, as well as the initizialization checking/learning to debug more carefully (before asking for help).

Answer (score 1):

Note that largestN, defined in line 45, it not initialized and can contain a very large value.
its very likely that IDEs like Code::blocks do zero all the variables where more optimization compilations produced by gcc do not.
As a result you may get very high "bars" which basically mess up your screen and make it very hard to see what was typed.

just change line 45 in the following way which would probably give you some more reasonable results:

```
//Declaration of variables for Histogram.
int currentLvl, largestN = 0, ii, iii, IV, V;
```

also, if you already at it, there's no need for i, ii, iii and so on, since you reset this counter every loop you can just use the same variable 'i' everywhere.
furthermore, its not standard-C but all modern compilers allows you to define a variable inside a for loop, which is safer (note the "int i" in the for loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; i++)
{
    // do something with i here. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, you're comparing to an uninitialized `largestN`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Here is another potential solution

```c
// pretend that wordLen[0] is the largest value. Now, largestN
// is initialized
largestN = wordLen[0];
// loop, now starting at the 2nd index since we know
// largestN == wordLen[0]
for (i=1; i<MAXLENGTH; i++)
{
   // use > here instead of >=. If equal, largestN already contains that
   // value, no sense in overwriting it with the same value
   if (wordLen[i] > largestN)
        largestN = wordLen[i];
    }
}
```

Here, you're only dealing with positive values, so intitalizing `largestN` to 0 as in the other answer is fine, but in general initializing to a value already in the array is the more robust approach.  What if your array has all negative numbers?  Then 0 would be greater than all of those and you wouldn't get an accurate result.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! thank you! especially the negative part, that would certainly put a cog in my programs' wheels in the future xD

Comment: @nyrx you're welcome! Another option is to `#include <limits.h>` and initialize `largestN = INT_MIN` or whatever it is, then loop thru all values in the array, but I prefer what I've shown here. Less things to remember/include, and one less iteration thru the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. There are *several* places where UB happens.
2. When storing into `wordLen`, `nw` can exceed `MAXLENGTH`
3. In your sample input file, there are more than 25 (i.e. `MAXLENGTH`) words.
4. We need a  check for overflow.
5. `largestN` is *uninitialized* so it can have a random [bad] value.
6. Some of the later arrays loop to `MAXLENGTH`. They should only loop to `nw` (the *actual* number of valid elements).
7. Some loops are hardwired to `25` instead of `MAXLENGTH`
8. The `level` array is defined too small.
9. Indexing from origin 1 exceeds the end of the array and leaves the first element unitialized.

---

Here is the [mostly] corrected code. It is annotated with [most of] the bugs and fixes. It probably still has some bugs in the printing but it fixes most of the serious bugs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef MAXLENGTH
#define MAXLENGTH 25                    /* Maximum length of input. */
#endif

int
main()
{

    /* Histogram of length of words in its input. Vertical or Horizontal. (Vertical is hardest, so let's do that!). Identify words and count characters within each, store that length in a array that represents the length for each word. Draw based on the number of words, their lengths, and their maximum height (optional). */

    /* Identify when inside of a word, start counting. When leaving word, record c-count into array, reset count to 0 after. Until entering new word. */

    // Declaration of the Counter's variables here
    // The Histogram's variables are farther down below!
    int nw,
     c,
     cCount,
     wordLen[MAXLENGTH];
    int i = nw = cCount = 0;

    // Initialize wordLen into 0 to avoid garbage results from any potential unused members of the array.
#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
#else
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; i++) {
#endif
        wordLen[i] = 0;
    }

    // Counts characters in each word and stores inside of chronological array.
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
// NOTE/FIX: this can overflow wordLen causing UB (it scribbles on unrelated
// memory)
#if 1
            if (nw >= MAXLENGTH) {
                printf("overflow\n");
                exit(99);
            }
#endif
            wordLen[nw] = cCount;
            ++nw;
            cCount = 0;

        }
        else {
            ++cCount;
        }

    }
    // Prints first 4 words lengths for comparison purposes.
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n\n", wordLen[0], wordLen[1], wordLen[2], wordLen[3]);

    // Declaration of variables for Histogram.
    int currentLvl,
     largestN,
     ii,
     iii,
     IV,
     V;

    // Finds and stores the largest number from the array into var:largestN.
// NOTE/BUG: some elements may not have _actual_ values and largestN is
// _unitialized_
#if 0
    for (ii = 0; ii < MAXLENGTH; ii++) {
#else
    largestN = 0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < nw; ii++) {
#endif
        if (wordLen[ii] >= largestN)
            largestN = wordLen[ii];
    }

    // Declare and initialize array for comparison purposes for later use in the Histogram generation process.
// NOTE/BUG: this defines an array that is too short
#if 0
    int level[largestN];
#else
    int level[largestN + 1];
#endif

    level[0] = 0;
// NOTE/BUG: this goes one beyond the end of the valid data and it starts with
// an origin 1 array index
#if 0
    for (iii = 1; iii < largestN + 1; iii++) {
        level[iii] = iii;
    }
#else
    for (iii = 0; iii < largestN; iii++) {
        level[iii] = iii;
    }
#endif
    // printf("\n largest N is %d\n", largestN); //for testing
    // printf("wordLen 0 is: %d\n", wordLen[0]); //for testing

    /* Histogram generation: The logic is simple: From Top-left, move rightwards (in chronological order) and check which of the words' lengths reach the current level or height (starting from Top). Print a line at that spot if they ever do, print an empty space if they do not. Then move one step down, and repeat the process but comparing 1 level lower. Until bottom is reached. */
    // ss
// NOTE/BUG: this starts at one past the valid data
#if 0
    for (V = largestN; V > 0; V--) {
#else
    for (V = largestN - 1; V >= 0; V--) {
#endif
        currentLvl = level[V];

// NOTE/BUG: not sure which of these is correct
#if 1
        for (IV = 0; IV < MAXLENGTH; IV++) {
#else
        for (IV = 0; IV < nw; IV++) {
#endif
            if (wordLen[IV] >= currentLvl)
                printf("|");
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`